# Is it possible to assign a variable to a dimension in a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, nifti

The size of my 3D array is (20, 33, 20). What I would like to do is to run a loop where, for instance, if there is a 0 in the 1st column (20), then the loop would go back to find a number that is non zero, then have the loop advance to the 2nd column (33) and do the same loop, and the same for the 3rd row also.

That was how I got the shape of the array. What I want to do is to have a variable assigned to each column so I can write loops

```
 import nibabel as nib 
 Example = nib.load("Example.nii")
 print Example.shape
```

Comment: Firstly it would help your explanation if you showed an example. Secondly, what code have you tried so far? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: @CoryKramer That was how I got the shape of the array. What I want to do is to have a variable assigned to each column so I can write loops